# What is the difference between “have interviewed” and “are interviewing” in this sentence?

Tags: present-tense, perfect-constructions, continuous

Could you please explain  the difference in meaning in the following sentences.

> 1. The detectives **have interviewed** two people this week.
> 2. The detectives **are interviewing** two people this week.

I think the first sentence implies that the detectives interviewed two people during unfinished period of time (it might be in the beginning or the end of the week). That is, they interviewed them and the process of interviewing other people will continue. The second implies that the detectives are still in the process of interviewing the two people during the week.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2):

You are mostly right.

The first sentence means that, as of now, interviews of  two people are completed (and this specifically refers to this week, so  the interviews took place between the beginning of the week and now). It suggests that interviewing may continue in the remainder of the week.

The second sentence means that the interviews are ongoing, and that there are two taking place this week. It suggests that no other interviews are planned this week.